# How to open a .flp file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-format

I have a .flp file from http://www.tes.co.uk/teaching-resource/Recorder-Planning-6181199/ which I would like to open.  It seems that this is an  ActivStudio Flipchart file.

How can I open it in linux/ubuntu?

Comment: Find an application that supports the *.flp file format in linux/ubuntu.  Might I suggest google as a start?

Comment: @mdpc That is of course where I started but I had no luck,

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

Okay, so I'm pretty sure it's a Activstudio Flipchart presentation file. I did a [TrID](http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx) scan on it and it's a 81.4% match

---

As far as I can tell, I'd say it's a `Fruity Loops Studio project` file.
But I could be wrong and it might actually be a `Flash Project` file. [More info here](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/flp).

What I do know for sure is that the `FLP` file you mention is a `ZIP` archive, so you could just rename it to `<SOMETHING>.ZIP` and you'll be able to see what's inside of it.

What I saw inside was several `FPG` files (no idea what those are) and `THM` files (which turned out to be just `BMP` bitmap files) and a bunch of other files.

Comment: Thanks. Now how do you actually open it?

Comment: You need to download and install [Activstudio Flipchart](https://moodle.rainhammark.com/mod/resource/view.php?id=9664)

Comment: That seems to be a Windows executable?

Comment: Yes, that's correct